# Plot a Histogram with Log scale in Mathematica 8

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, logging, histogram

I need to plot a Histogram in Mathematica 8 where only the y axis is in Log scale. 
Anyone?

Cheers

Comment: It took me about 3s to find how to do this from Mathematica's help.  So yes, I can do it.

Comment: Yes.  If you have a specific problem, post your code and let us have a look at it.

Comment: This is not really a programming problem. In my view, it belongs on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ (but please check the documentation before asking over there!)

Answer (score 4):

Directly quoting the *Mathematica* 7 documentation:

> Histogram[{*x*<sub>1</sub>, *x*<sub>2</sub>, ...}, *w*, *hspec*] plots
>   a histogram with bin heights computed according to the specification
>   *hspec*.

and:

> Different forms of histogram can be obtained by giving different bin height specifications *hspec* in Histogram[*data*, *w*, *hspec*]. 
>   The following forms can be used:
>
> - "Count" the number of values lying in each bin
> - "Probability"   fraction of values lying in each bin
> - "ProbabilityDensity"    fraction of values divided by bin width
> - "LogCount", "LogProbability", "LogProbabilityDensity"   logarithmic heights
> - fh  heights obtained by applying fh to bins and counts

Therefore try:

```
Histogram[data, Automatic, "LogCount"]
```

Comment: To be fair, the [v.8 docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Histogram.html) does not say anything about "LogCount". An example is given for using ["Log"](http://wolfram.com/xid/0rtcbb4ia-g57qmz), but in the top part of the doc it is indicated that the form is `{"Log", hspec}` which the example does not use. But, as the example is easily found, extrapolating it to the "correct" form or to the y-axis should not be difficult.

Comment: Yes, it does, strangely enough.

Comment: @rcollyer, Mr.Wizard: `Histogram` was modified a good deal in v8. There are several changes to the third argument, mostly additional functionality. To go with the new, shorter forms of `"CDF"`, `"SF"`, `"CHF"`, etc., `"ProbabilityDensity"` was changed to `"PDF"` and I guess, similarly for `"LogCount"`... the old options still work though, for backward compatibility.

Comment: I like undocumented `LogProbability`!